# Usage of “as well”

Tags: grammar

Are these usages of "as well" grammatically correct?

*Going back on the deal, he said, could result in Taiwan being “regarded as an unreliable trade partner” by China as well other countries with which the island wants to negotiate free-trade pacts. (The Economist)*

*Fire TV gives viewers access to content from Amazon’s video-streaming service, as well those of Netflix and others. (The Economist)*

Comment: If possible, please provide actual links to the text. Something seems askew.

Comment: Here are the links to the articles. http://www.economist.com/news/asia/21599807-students-occupy-taiwans-legislature-protest-against-free-trade-pact-china-manning  http://www.economist.com/news/world-week/21600183-business-week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knee-jerk reaction seeing a quote from *The Economist* was to say yes, it is grammatical!  However, after reading and re-reading the sentences multiple times, I really do think it needs to be "as well as".  I've never seen a case where one can simply drop the second "as" in as well as.  Searching on Google doesn't yield many results either.  It's definitely intelligible and it actually took me a few readings to catch it.

> I bought the apples you wanted as well *as* some other items too.
>
> I bought the apples you wanted as well some other items too.

I think the second one sounds stranger each time I read it.

Comment: Although 'I bought the apples you wanted, and some other items too' doesn't sound unnatural with the semantically redundant _too_, which adds emphasis, _I bought the apples you wanted as well as some other items too_ sounds unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the corrections in bold. Both uses of 'as well' need to be followed by the word 'as'

> Going back on the deal, he said, could result in Taiwan being
>   “regarded as an unreliable trade partner” by China as well **as** other
>   countries with which the island wants to negotiate free-trade pacts.
>   (The Economist)
>
> Fire TV gives viewers access to content from Amazon’s video-streaming
>   service, as well **as** those of Netflix and others. (The Economist)